# flutter - don't show notification when user is on certain page

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications

My app has chatting function. And I have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging and Local Notification.

So when someone sends me a message, notification(one inside android status bar) and local notification(one on the upper part of the screen that holds for like 3 seconds) is shown. They show up when app is opened, on background, and also when app is terminated. (So far so good)

But I don't want both notifications(1. fcm notification, 2. local notification) to show up when I'm already in the chat page with that person. And I have no idea where to start.

Below is my code for handling fcm and show local notification. They are inside main.dart and the main function calls initializeFCM before returning my root page.

```
Future<void> initializeFCM() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  // Firebase Messaging
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    // print('User granted permission');
  } else
  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    // print('User granted provisional permission');
  } else {
    // print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
  }



  // Get any messages which caused the application to open from
  // a terminated state.
  RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await messaging.getInitialMessage();

  if (initialMessage != null) {
    handleMessage(initialMessage);
  }


  // initialize local notification
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  // terminated app을 local notification 눌러서 열었을 때 - payload가 정상적으로 동작하지 않음
  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  final didNotificationLaunchApp = notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;
  if (didNotificationLaunchApp) {
    onSelectNotification(notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload);
  }


  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    showLocalNotification(message);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(showLocalNotification);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
}


void handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
  if (message.data["screen"] == "message") {
    Navigator.push(
        navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MessageListPage(),
        )
    );
  }
}

Future<void> onSelectNotification(payload) async {
  if(payload != null) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(payload);

    if (data['screen'] == "message") {
      Navigator.push(
          navigatorKey.currentContext!,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MessageListPage(),
          )
      );
    }
  }
}


Future<void> showLocalNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  // String screen = message.data['screen'];

  // iOS heads up notification setting
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  // android channel setting
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    importance: Importance.max,
  );

  // initialize local notification
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/mentea_ic_stat_name'),
      iOS: IOSInitializationSettings()),
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  // If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
  // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    // print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'high_importance_channel', //channel.id,
          'High Importance Notifications', //channel.name,
          icon: android.smallIcon,
          color: primaryColor,
          // other properties...
        ),
      ),
      payload: json.encode(message.data)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add an array of UserIds or "UserId, UserId, ..." string in the chatroom database. make an observable method in the chat room screen and update that value when the user will enter the user's chat screen.  check if the array or ',' separated string contains receiver UserID then no need to fire push & local notification. and remove user id when user not present in the chat room screen.

Comment: @VishalZaveri That did the trick. Thank you. I made 'currentlyMessaging' field in user profile database and compared message sender with it before sending fcm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but I'll post my solution here.

It happens that when we send a push notification with the notification message feature, the FCM plugin automatically sends a notification on the device if the App is in background and finished, where we can only customize the foreground notification through Local Notifications or other solutions within of the App. So the solution pointed out in the Firebase documentation for this situation is to send the push notification only as a data message, without including the notification object. Below I show the examples and the documentation link.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=1&hl=pt#notifications_and_data_messages

Combined notification example:

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: '$FooCorp up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$FooCorp gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
  },
  data: {
    stock: 'GOOG',
    open: '829.62',
    close: '635.67'
  }
};
```

Notification example with data message only:

```
const payload = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  }
};
```

Notification example with notification message only:

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: '$FooCorp up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$FooCorp gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
  }
};
```

So, so that you can customize all forms of notification (foreground, background and terminated), send a push notification through your backend as a data message only.